# snapshot connectionstate is always waiting while using stream as FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged

Tags: android, flutter, dart

i am trying to create an authentication using **firebase_auth** using email and password the code has 3 pages 1.Main page where it checks  if the connection has established or user is already logged in or not. and navigates to the respective pages which is done by a function `_handleWidnowDisplay()` .

But for some reason the app is stuck in `if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){}` block and doesn't connect to firebase .

While adding the firebase dependencies i had some issues which was solved by adding `android.useAndroidX=true` and `android.enableJetifier=true` to **gradel.properties**.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'screens/MyLogin.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'screens/MainPage.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MaterialApp(
      color: Colors.red,
      home: _handleWidnowDisplay(),
    ));

Widget _handleWidnowDisplay() {
  return StreamBuilder(
    stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged,
    builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
        return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: new Text("MyLogin"),
              backgroundColor: Colors.red.shade900,
            ),
            body: new Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                color: Colors.red.shade900,
                child: new Center(
                  child: new Text("Loding....."),
                )));
      } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
        return MainPAge();
      } else {
        return MyLogin();
      }
    },
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is stuck in waiting, my first instinct will be to check your device's connectivity. Edit the AndroidManifest.xml to allow INTERNET_PERMISSION. I dont see the methodto actually log in, thus changing the status to not waiting so make sure that is actually being called.

Comment: i solved it by making the project as  Androidx but i appreciate the help though thanks

Comment: How you can solve this problem? I have the same issue.